# add jar to eclipse plugin (hadoop)

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jar, hadoop

I need to run an Eclipse (Indigo version) plugin, but from the error log I find out that I am missing 2 jars.

How can I add the missing jar to Eclipse so that I can run the plugin?

Is there a way to add the jar to the existing plugin?

If this is of any help, I try to run Hadoop Map/Reduce perspective and I found out that I should add commons-configuration and commons-lang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to just copy the Jar file(s) into your plugin project, and then go to the plugin manifest (open the MANIFEST.MF file) and add them to the classpath on the Runtime Tab. Also on the Build tab, make sure they are checked so that they are included in the output of the plugin.

There are other ways, like making a special plugin to house only the required Jar files, or get the bundle (plugin) that might already contain that Jar file from someplace like [Orbit](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20110523182458/).

Comment: and how do I do this if the plugin is just a jar file?

Comment: Oh, so you are not developing the plugin, you just found it. My comments were about developing a plugin. Normally when you are using a plugin, it's really a set of plugins that you install with the installer (p2) and it makes sure you have all of the required plugins. Can you elaborate more on what this plugin is any why you can't use the installer to install it?

Comment: the way I use the plugin is just drop the .jar file in the plugin folder under Eclipse, and somehow it seems that I am missing two jars, but I do not know where to place the jars

Comment: You can get the bundles you seek at http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20110523182458/ and put them in the same way.